# Make Discord Bot receive file and send the contents to the channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I want to make it so that if I do this:

1. I use !command in the channel..
2. (The bot asks for a file)
3. I send a file

The bot should then read the file and send the contents.

I tried:

```
await message.channel.send("Send your file please..");

const MSG1 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync(`${msg.url}`);

  message.channel.send('Read the file! Fetching data...');
  message.channel.send(buffer)
})
```

and

```
await message.channel.send("Send your file please..");

const MSG1 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => {
  fs.readFile(Buffer.from(MSG1.attachments.first()), 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Read the file! Fetching data...');
    console.log(data);
  })
})
```

and

```
await message.channel.send("Send your file please..");

const MSG1 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => {
  fs.readFile(Buffer.from(`${msg.attachments.first().attachment}`), 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Read the file! Fetching data...');
    console.log(data);
  })
})
```

and

```
await message.channel.send("Send your file please..");

const MSG1 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(msg => {
  let buffer = Buffer.from(msg.attachments.first().attachment)

  message.channel.send('Read the file! Fetching data...');
  message.channel.send(buffer)
})
```

But none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using [TextChannel.awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) as if it had a callback argument, but that function you're passing should be a [filter](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/typedef/CollectorFilter). Instead of using `awaitMessages(function)` use `awaitMessages().then(function)`.

With that said, I also suggest to use a filter and get the attachment only if the author is the same:

```
let filter = m => m.author == message.author; //use that message only if the author is the same
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1}).then(msg => {
  let file = msg.attachments.first().file;
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    msg.channel.send("Read the file! Fetching data...");
    msg.channel.send(data);
  });
});
```

That should work, let me know if you have problems with it